# What is an example implementation of Exit code for Haskell program that returns back to default Prelude> screen GHC 7.8.3

Tags: haskell, exit, terminate, exit-code

I am new to haskell programming. I would like an example code of how I can quit a main program by entering a command (for example QUIT)and go back to the default Prelude> screen. I am using the GHC 7.8.3 interpreter. Please also mention which which module(s) I would need to import if any. I have been searching all over and trying different things but nothing seems to work. Really want to know how to do this asap. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but if you run `main` from GHCI, if it completes with any error code (that is, it doesn't crash), you return to the interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This SO answer contains a basic read-execute loop: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27094682/866915

When you see the `Prelude>` prompt you are operating within the program `ghci`, and you will get back to that prompt when the function you've called returns.

An abbreviated example:

```
main = do
  let loop = do putStr "Type QUIT to quit: "
                str <- getLine
                if str == "QUIT"
                  then return ()
                  else loop
  loop
```

Comment: Very good. On point of what I was looking for. My knowlege is increasing and now I can pratice some of my own variations :). Thank you very much

Answer (score 8):

You can use one of the functions from [the `System.Exit` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/System-Exit.html).  The simplest use would probably be something like this:

```
import System.Exit (exitSuccess)

main = exitSuccess
```

Of course, it is not of great utility in this example, but you can place it anywhere an `IO ()` can be used, and it will terminate the program. In GHCi, the exception it throws will be caught, and you will return to the `Prelude>` prompt after an `*** Exception: ExitSuccess` line.